How to fill this face with mesh line？

I created this shape using geometry nodes, but I don't know how to fill the mesh with topology through geometry nodes. I have used curve to mesh, but I am unable to correctly stitch the upper boundary points (because the distribution of points extruded  by circles is uneven, while filling with grids or curve to mesh is uniform)

Add a grid and merge by distance?

It can't be soved ,because the cirle's point is not Uniformly distributed on a quadrilateral，if you add a grid，it cannot merged perfectly

when the topology becomes complex，merge by distance will broken the shape  easily

Not at all, unless you're creating really really tiny topology, then you decrease the distance.

Can we assume that (1) the hole is a quad, with only 4 "sharp" corners, (2) it is a 2D XY geometry ?

Unfortunately, Daniel is exactly right. In geonodes you need to spawn a grid and merge with the rest. You need to use maths to spawn the grid exactly right, however.

This is what frustrates me. I want to generate a perfect topology of a quadrilateral circle through calculation, but I can only piece together the geometriy nodes one by one. When I finally pieced together this quadrilateral, I got stuck, and in the end, I could only get a similar one

Can you do it the other way round, starting with the quad, then making the circle ? From inside to outside, inside of outside to inside ?

I have tried ,but make quad to circle is difficult ，the point’s position is hardly to transform. now I get a new way ,I just make a very simple  circle with 8 edge,make it perfect ,and use the Subdivision Surface nodes，it looks very well. It's always easier to go from simple to complex than from complex to simple

But there is a drawback to this, the number of edges can only be controlled by the subdivision level, which cannot display the total number of edges more intuitively

Could you confirm that this is what you are trying to achieve ? https://i.sstatic.net/itvBAygj.png. It is made with GN starting with the grid and some maths to shape the circle.

Yes，that what I want，it‘s hard to me

Great, I will post the answer tomorrow afternoon. Merry Christmas !

U too，Merry Christmas！

May I suggest to change the title in something more focus, like "How to fill a quadrilateral surface inside a disk" ?

(Using Blender 4.2.5)
Overview
The proposed procedure firstly builds a XY grid, centered on the origin of the object to which the GeometryNodes modifier is attached, and it tags its vertices. Then the border vertices, save the four corners, are moved to match the enclosing circle. Eventually, corners are moved to match the enclosing circle.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.5+)
GeometryNodes modifier

Figure 1: GeometryNodes modifier main graph and setup.
Dark green nodes: Tagging points
The Tag node group is capturing in Point domain the "Type" attribute equal to:

3 for a point along a vertical border,
4 for a point inside,
5 for a corner,
6 for a point along a horizontal border.

Dark pink nodes: Moving borders
Points along a vertical border, i.e. with "Type" equal to 3, are moved in X direction by the Inflate X group node. While points along a horizontal border, i.e. with "Type" equal to 6, are moved in Y direction by the Inflate Y group node. Border points are selected for the associated Set Position node taking advantage of the Modulo function. Indeed, 3(mod 3)=6(mod 3)=0, and this 0 integer value is converted into False as a boolean value. Consequently, Not("Type"(mod 3)) is True only for "Type" equal to 3 and 6.
Dark blue nodes: Moving corners
Corners, i.e. points with "Type" equal to 5, are moved along the perpendicular bisector of the line segment connecting their displaced adjacent border points. This position dividing in half the corner arc length is computed by the Inflate Corner group node.
Tag group node

Figure 2: Graph tagging a point according its position inside the grid. (a) Edge tag ; (b) Point tag in float algebra ; (c) Point tag in integer algebra.
A discriminant attribute to separate Points "Type" is computed by combining Edges attributes linearly:

Border edges: (see dark green nodes) Such an edge is belonging to only one face, while an inner edge belongs to two faces. This Face Count attribute is returned by the Edge Neighbors node. Through boolean to integer type casting, this attribute is evaluated as "1" for a border edge, and as "0" for an inner one.
Horizontal edges: (see dark pink nodes) By construction with the Grid node, the second vertex of an edge has a higher X or Y coordinate compared to its first vertex. Consequently, horizontal edges are separated from vertical ones by a Greater Than zero X variation with a Y variation equal to zero (i.e. Greater Than -1). Once again through boolean to integer type casting, this attribute is evaluated as "1" for a horizontal edge, and as "0" for a vertical one. This value is then multiplied by 7 (see the discussion afterwards about this factor).

Adding both attributes yields (see Fig.(2a)):

0 for inner vertical edges,
1 for border vertical edges,
7 for inner horizontal edges,
8 for border horizontal edges.

The interpolation triggered by the Capture Attribute node from Edge domain to Point domain, using Float or Integer algrebra, yields (see Fig.(2b) and Fig.(2c) respectively):

for a point along a vertical border: (1+7+1)/3=9/3=3, rounded up to 3.
for a point inside: (7+0+7+0)/4=14/4=3.5, rounded up to 4.
for a corner: (1+8)/2=9/2=4.5, rounded up to 5.
for a point along a horizontal border: (8+0+8)/3=16/3=5.33, rounded up to 6.

The factor 7 was found by trial and error until four distinct "Type" values were returned. It is by chance that these values ​​follow each other (see the section "Mathematical curiosity" at the end of the post for a more rational selection of the linear combination).
Inflate X and Inflate Y group nodes

Figure 3: Graphs computing position along the enclosing circle, while keeping Y or X coordinate unchanged.
The coordinates of points along a circle in the XY plane, of radius $R$, and centered on the origin of the object to which the GeometryNodes modifier is attached, are such that:
$$
X^2 + Y^2 = R^2
$$
Consequently, the X coordinate of points along a vertical border is updated as (see Inflate X group node):
$$
X' = \text{sgn}{(X)} \sqrt{R^2 - Y^2}
$$
And the Y coordinate of points along a horizontal border is updated as (see Inflate Y group node):
$$
Y' = \text{sgn}{(Y)} \sqrt{R^2 - X^2}
$$
The $\text{sgn}{()}$ function is moving "outwards" all the border points, taking advantage that the grid is centered on the object origin.
Inflate Corner group node

Figure 4: Graph computing corners position along the enclosing circle, and illustration of vertices $C$, $V$ and $H$.
Let $C$ be a corner vertex to update, and $V$ and $H$ be the vertices to which $C$ is connected by an edge, initially vertical or horizontal respectively. It is assumed that $V$ and $H$ are already moved on the enclosing circle. To evenly divide the circular arc between $V$ and $H$, $C$ is located along the perpendicular bisector of $\vec{VH}$. Let $I$ be the mid point of $\vec{VH}$. The position of $C$ is computed as (see Inflate Corner group node):
$$
\vec{OC} = R \times \frac{\vec{OI}}{\| \vec{OI} \|} = R \times \frac{\vec{OV}+\vec{OH}}{\| \vec{OV}+\vec{OH} \|}
$$
where the redundant $\frac{1}{2}$ factor is omitted, and the $\vec{\bullet}/{\| \vec{\bullet} \|}$ operator is evaluated by a Normalize vector math node.
The Neighbor group node is returning the position of $V$ and $H$. To do so, the index of one of the two edges connected to $C$ is firstly recovered using an Edges of Vertex node, by linking the index of $C$ to the Vertex Index socket. The selection of the edge connected to $V$ (resp. $H$, the order being irrelevant) is controlled by the Sort Index socket. Then the indices of $V$ (resp. $H$) and $C$ are recovered by an Edge Vertices node, and their addition is triggered by a Sample Index node set in Edge domain. By subtracting the index of $C$, only remains the index of $V$ (resp. $H$). This index is eventually input in an other Sample Index node, set in Point domain, to get the Position of $V$ (resp. $H$).

Mathematical curiosity
Considering a Grid mesh primitive, let $a$ be the tag of a border edge (0 otherwise), and $b$ be the tag of a horizontal edge (0 otherwise). What should be the values of $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{N}^*$ such that after interpolation from Edge domain to Point domain, the tag of points is in $\mathbb{N}^*$ also, and it is discriminating points along horizontal borders, from points along vertical borders, from corners, from points inside the grid ?
Adding both edge tags yields:

$0$ for inner vertical edges,
$a$ for border vertical edges,
$b$ for inner horizontal edges,
$a+b$ for border horizontal edges.

The interpolation from Edge domain to Point domain yields:

for a corner: $c=\frac{1}{2}\left[(a)+(a+b)\right] \Leftrightarrow 2a+b=2c$
for a point along a vertical border: $v=\frac{1}{3}\left[(a)+(b)+(a)\right] \Leftrightarrow 2a+b=3v$
for a point along a horizontal border: $h=\frac{1}{3}\left[(a+b)+(0)+(a+b)\right] \Leftrightarrow 2a+2b=3h$
for a point inside: $i=\frac{1}{4}\left[(b)+(0)+(b)+(0)\right] \Leftrightarrow b=2i$

From this system of linear Diophantine equations, $b=3(h-v)$ and $b=2i$ yield:

$b$ is divisible by 2 and 3, i.e. $b=6n$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$
$b \gt 0 \Leftrightarrow h \gt v$

And $2a+b=2c$ and $2a+b=3v$ yield:

$2c=3v$, i.e. $v$ is divisible by 2 and $c$ is divisible by 3, i.e. $v=2m$ and $c=3m$ with $m \in \mathbb{N}^*$
$c \gt v$

$(c, v, h, i)$ and $(a, b)$ are thus completely defined by $(m,n)$ as:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
c & = & 3m \\
v & = & 2m \\
h & = & 2(m+n) \\
i & = & 3n \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
a & = & 3(m-n) \\
b & = & 6n \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
The expression of $a$ yields $m \gt n$.
Adding the arbitrary condition that $c \gt h$ yields:
$$
3m \gt 2(m+n)  \Leftrightarrow m \gt 2n
$$
Choosing the minimal value of $m$ as $m=2n+1$ yields:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
c & = & 6n+3 \\
v & = & 4n+2 \\
h & = & 6n+2 \\
i & = & 3n \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
a & = & 3n+3 \\
b & = & 6n \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Consequently, $i \lt v \lt h \lt c$.
Choosing $n=1$ yields $(c, v, h, i)=(9, 6, 8, 3)$ and $(a, b)=(6, 6)$.
